# How to get aggregate data weekwise using Entity Framework

Tags: linq, entity-framework, sum, aggregate

I have a backend table named "VideoData" which has data in the following form:

```
    VideoID       RecordingStarted         RecordingEnded
    ==============================================================
    abc123        2013-03-01 15:30:00      2013-03-01 15:40:00        
    def123        2013-03-06 12:00:00      2013-03-06 12:40:00
    ijk123        2013-03-10 11:00:00      2013-03-10 11:05:00
    klm123        2013-03-12 10:05:00      2013-03-12 10:25:00
    And list goes on .......
    .......................
    .............................
```

Using Entity Framework I want to get Total Hours of Video captured for example for the month of March 2013, in such a way that total hours of captured video come as Weekwise.
Example in the following manner:

```
    Mar 1, 2013     Mar 8, 2013      Mar 15, 2013     Mar 22, 2013
   ================================================================
   500              300              350              200
```

I have googled much, but could not figure out a way on how to do it exactly. Please guide.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: values in the resulting table are minutes?

Comment: No, they would be in hours. i.e Number of hours of captured video done in that week. Actually I have to show this data on a Graph at front end.

Comment: Do you want to `Mar 1` be always the **first** day of the resulting table? `Mar 1` is friday, so should you start from monday `Mar 4` of exactly `Mar 8`

Comment: Actually if we take march 1 as start of collecting our weekly data then next day would be 8 march. So yes we will surely take into consideration March 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hate to overrule Ilya's excellent job (sorry mate, at least I upvoted you), but since this is entity framework it is possible to let the database do the job in just one query by using [SqlFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.aspx):

```cs
context.Videos.Select(t => new
  {
      Year = SqlFunctions.DatePart("yyyy", t.RecordingStarted),
      Week = SqlFunctions.DatePart("ww", t.RecordingStarted),
      Hours = SqlFunctions.DateDiff("hh", t.RecordingStarted, t.RecordingEnded)
  })
.GroupBy(x => new { x.Year, x.Week} )
.Select (x => new { x.Key.Year, x.Key.Week, TotalHours = x.Sum(p => p.Hours)} )
```

The output will be something like

```
2013  9 500
2013 10 300
...
```

To get from year + week to a date is remarkably hard in Sql Server. If this really is a requirement you may consider building a reference table with year + week numbers and date of the first day. Or fetch the data in memory (`.ToList()`) and use C# to convert the data.

Comment: +1, great solution, it also could be using in linq to objects by grouping by year and week and them summing.

Comment: Hey @Gert, great job but this I also had done in my controller class earlier, only got confused on how to bring in the dates with 7 days gap in between them. Can you explain in some detail, last para of your answer? Thanks

Comment: In sql server there are all these functions to get date parts (years, weeks, days, etc. etc.) from a date. But not the other way around. It is a fairly easy one-time job to build a table with week numbers and dates in the data base (start at some date in a cursor and continue for as many dates you're going to need) and join to this table in queries. In C# most of the times you will find an algorithm by googling.

Answer (score 2):

So ok, this task seems to be quite interesting. I've implemented basic functionality with local data. Fell free to comment for more functionality. It's a little-bit messy thou

```
//local data for testing
var data = new[] {
    new {VideoId = "abc123",RecordindStarted = DateTime.Parse("2013-03-01 15:30:00"),RecordingEnded = DateTime.Parse("2013-03-01 15:40:00")},        
    new {VideoId = "def123",RecordindStarted = DateTime.Parse("2013-03-06 12:00:00"),RecordingEnded = DateTime.Parse("2013-03-06 12:40:00")},
    new {VideoId = "de1223",RecordindStarted = DateTime.Parse("2013-03-06 12:30:00"),RecordingEnded = DateTime.Parse("2013-03-06 12:50:00")},
    new {VideoId = "ijk123",RecordindStarted = DateTime.Parse("2013-03-10 11:00:00"),RecordingEnded = DateTime.Parse("2013-03-10 11:05:00")},
    new {VideoId = "klm123",RecordindStarted = DateTime.Parse("2013-03-12 10:05:00"),RecordingEnded = DateTime.Parse("2013-03-12 10:25:00")},
    new {VideoId = "klm123",RecordindStarted = DateTime.Parse("2013-03-12 10:05:00"),RecordingEnded = DateTime.Parse("2013-03-13 10:25:00")},
};


var calendar = new GregorianCalendar();

var ungroupedTotalHours = data.Select(d => GetHoursPerDays(d.RecordindStarted, d.RecordingEnded));

var groupedTotalHours = 
         ungroupedTotalHours.SelectMany(v => v)
                            .GroupBy(v=> v.Key)
                            .ToDictionary(v => v.Key, v => v.Sum(val => val.Value));

var result = 
 groupedTotalHours.GroupBy(v =>calendar.GetWeekOfYear( v.Key, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Monday))
                  .ToDictionary(v => "Week "+ v.Key, row => row.Sum(val => val.Value));

Console.WriteLine ( string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result.Select(r => r.Key +" has "+r.Value+" hours")) );
```

core logic goes to this method:

```
public IDictionary<DateTime, int> GetHoursPerDays(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    if(end.Date == start.Date)
        return new Dictionary<DateTime, int>{{start.Date, (end -  start).Minutes}};
    return Enumerable.Range(1, (int)(end -  start).TotalHours)
                    .Select(v => start.AddHours(v))
                    .GroupBy(v => v.Date)
                    .ToDictionary( v => v.Key, r => r.Count());
}
```

prints:

```
Week 9 has 10 hours
Week 10 has 65 hours
Week 11 has 44 hours
```

Comment: @llya. Thanks for spending time and excellent work but I guess it needs a little bit correction. In your first block it should be "GetHoursPerDays" instead of "GetHours". Am I right ?

Comment: One more thing. Instead of Weeks as you have written on console, can it be dates e.g March 1, 2013 then March 8, 2013.....

Comment: Hate to refactor from SO site. Corrected.